# Laravel custom Helper class -- can't call non-static methods from other classes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to use the Config::get() method in my custom Helper class, but always get an error.

At the top of a Helper.php file I have the following:

```
use \Illuminate\Config\Repository as Config;
```

Then, I have a public static function in which I want to get use the Config::get() method to grab a config setting. For simplicity, let's pretend the function is:

```
public static function getURL() {
    return Config::get('assets.url');
}
```

I have an assets.php file with this url variable set. The Config::get('assets.url') method works elsewhere in my site.

But when trying to use Config::get in my Helper.php file, i get this error:

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Config\Repository::get() should not be called statically
```

I obviously can't change the Config::get method to a static one. What can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try just importing the **Facade** instead of trying to get the underlying class.

```
use Config;
```

Then just use `Config` like normal in your class.

Comment: Hey it doesn't work? Says Config not found, I do this: use \Config as CF;


function config($config, $default = null)
{

    return CF::get($config, $default);
}